# AutoHotKey switch some lowercase and upperkeys buttons, duplicated buttons identification

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a java developer and need some buttons to have switched cases.

As example:

- `[` should be `{` and vice versa, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> should be `[` (Because I need `{` more often than `[`)
- `9` should be `(` and vice versa <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> should be `9`

  1. I've tried some variations, but all stacked in recursion, any ideas?
  2. I have duplicated button <kbd>\</kbd> on my keyboard + symbol <kbd>\</kbd> in other layout. How can i assign different actions on each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Romale,

Try to see if this will work.

```
\::Send LC ;  \ modyfies the "normal" \ to LC (or whatever..)
+\::Send UC ; +\ modyfies the shift \ to UC (or whatever..)
```

Here I can only test this with one \ key. You might have to use the +[lowercase char] to address the second .

Alternatively you can try to find the ScanCode of each key. You do that with right-clicking on the AHK Icon, then select [Open], the in the Application press [Ctrl]+k. now press one \ and then [F5]. Then press the other \ and [F5] again.
The ScanCodes are in the second column.

If you want to act on the ScanCodes (e.g. SC 165), you use the following:

```
SC165::Send ABC
```

Or if you want to do more...

```
SC165::
TrayTip, Key has been Changed, Magnifier
Send ABC
Return
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Romale,

Try this and let me know

```
${::send [
$[::Send {{} ; { or } needs to be placed between {}
```

Regards.

B.t.w. maybe you can even swap the [ and ] keys on your keyboard. Swap left and right and place upside down.

Comment: It works! Thank you. 
Any ideas about duplicated button on keyboard?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Try to give some more details.

Comment: I have two similar buttons on my keyboard:
lowercase="\", uppercase="\" (near leftShift and Enter)
How can i bind (differ) each of them?

Comment: I've binded all required keys in that way.
Except for one: '%'
$%::send 5
$5::send {%}
error occurs, any ideas?

Comment: Romale,  not sure what you mean. When I try "$%::Send, Hello" (without the ") it outputs "Hello" hen I press % (shift 5). What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Proper answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176757/autohotkey-window-appear-event

Comment: One more issue detected with this code:
${::send [ $[::Send {{}
On second keyboard layout (russian), under this button is 'x' symbol. So it sends '{' or '[' on second layout too, it's wrong.

Comment: Romale, does this mean that you use two different keyboards? When you want to program two keyboards and have them work differently, you have to use an other program called HIDMacros (http://www.hidmacros.eu). Here you can program each device (keyboards and mice) how to respond.

Comment: Or is it that you use one keyboard and you switch from Roman to Cyrillic and the same key has a different meaning? Would using the scancodes work better? Not sure if the scancodes remain the same with different keyboard drivers.

Comment: Same key has different meaning. One key sends different symbols depending on layout. But AHK overrides 2nd layout symbol that should be sended. That's strange because i haven't binded cyrillic one. 
Can i fix that? Or i have to use not obvious scancodes or each time overload the source with layout checking?

Comment: When I switch between two different keyboard drivers (US vs Dutch) I see that the same key sends a different character. In both situations the key uses the same ScanCode, so when I use SCxxx::Send, W the key that previously sent different characters now only sends W in any situation.

Comment: I use $[::Send {{}. And I receive '{' anyway in other layout instead of 'x' symbol.