# Autohotkey window appear event

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using WorkRave rest reminder and want to turn off my screen when the rest window appears.
I know how to turn it off.

How create an event when specified window (#IfWinActive ahk_class ...) appears?

Also, can i bind % symbol? {%} doesn't work, instead of other ones.

Comment: Romale, Can you open the windows spy when this WorkRave rest reminder is active? You open the Windows Spy by a right-click on the AHK icon. The Window Spy will always be on-top,. When you activate the WorkRave screen, you should see the details (incl. ahk_class). I don't know what it is that you want to do with the % sign.

Comment: Romale, any luck so far?

Comment: 1. Windows spy can't catch workrave's first stay on top warning. But i've catched it through window list (ahk_class ). How can i bind an action, when it appears?
2. Example, not works: 
5::{%}
%::{5}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To have an instant notification of a window appearing, use a Shell Hook. This is sometimes so fast that autohotkey can react before you even see the window yourself.

A shell hook is demonstrated on the [AutoHotkey Forum](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=123323).

An example with your usage (almost copied verbatim from the forum post):

```
#Persistent
SetBatchLines, -1
Process, Priority,, High

Gui +LastFound
hWnd := WinExist()

DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,hWnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam,lParam )
{
    If ( wParam = 1 ) ;  HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED := 1
    {
        WinGetTitle, Title, ahk_id %lParam%
        If  ( Title = "WorkRest" )
            WinClose, ahk_id %lParam% ; close it immideately
    }
}
```

If you want to use a literal % symbol in a command, escape it with AutoHotkey's escape character, the backtick ` (on the same key as ~ on a US keyboard) like so:

```
MsgBox You are 200`% awesome!
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works great! Take a look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/266240/16847) as well. Can you design your script to do that as well? I.e. detect all existing windows as well and see if previously seen or not?

Comment: This does not work wen two windows are opened in short time. Do you have some solution for that as wel?

Comment: @botenvouwer if you miss events you're probably taking too long to process the previous event.  The key is that the next ShellMessage can't run until the previous one completes, but ShellMessage can interrupt other code.  So change ShellMessage to add the message data to a global queue object and return immediately, then process the message queue in a separate loop/timer to do your window/gui/mouse/keyboard etc commands that are relatively slow.

Comment: @Vijay Look into `WinGet, List` to list windows.

Answer (score 0):

Romale,

You can try this, but since I don't use WorkRave, I can't test it.

```
; This next line needs to be added at the top of the AHK file, so it will be started as soon as AHK starts.
; Every 120000 ms, it will launch the "WorkRave:" script to check if a window with WorkRave exists.
SetTimer, WorkRave,120000 ; Run WorkRaveTester every 2 minutes = 120000


; Somewhere else in the AHK file.....
WorkRave: ; This is the label for the WorkRave script
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; 2 = Matches the string WorkRave anywhere in the window title of IfWinExist
IfWinExist, WorkRave ; When WorkRave window exists
{
  TrayTip, WorkRave, Started ,1 ; Or whatever you want to do here....
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open WorkRave
2. Right Click > Preferences > User Interface > Block mode: No blocking > Close
3. Save code below as **WorkRave Close Rest Reminder Window.ahk**

```
    #NoEnv
    SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
    #Warn
    CoordMode, Mouse, Window
    SendMode Input
    #SingleInstance Force
    SetTitleMatchMode 2
    SetTitleMatchMode Fast
    DetectHiddenWindows Off
    DetectHiddenText On
    #WinActivateForce
    #NoTrayIcon
    SetControlDelay 1
    SetWinDelay 0
    SetKeyDelay -1
    SetMouseDelay -1
    SetBatchLines -1
    #Persistent
    #MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

    WorkRaveCloseRestReminderWindow:
    Loop
    {
        WinWait, Rest break ahk_class gdkWindowToplevel ahk_exe Workrave.exe
        WinClose, Rest break ahk_class gdkWindowToplevel ahk_exe Workrave.exe
        Run, TurnOffScreen
    }
    Return
```